# Increase Stack Size on Azure App Service - Editbin

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, iis

I have a very similar but not exactly the same issue as

1. [Increase Stack size IIS ASP.NET 3.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2319711/increase-stack-size-iis-asp-net-3-5)
2. [StackOverflow when hosted as WCF - works fine in Console app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1645377/stackoverflow-when-hosted-as-wcf-works-fine-in-console-app)
3. [probably more]

In fact I used the answers to be able to debug the app locally on my PC.

The difference with the other questions is that I have some old code in .net Framework 4.8 that I need to put on an Asp.Net Web API on Azure.
Is there a way to install the command EDITBIN on the app service?

From Kudu I see that the executable that is used on the app service is `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\inetsrv\w3wp.exe [...]`

And I can navigate to that directory but obviously the command EDITBIN is not installed.
Is there a way I can do it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

[Run Process on special thread and await result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54655372/run-process-on-special-thread-and-await-result)

I found a solution where I can run the old code in a dedicated thread where I can specify it's stack size.